# How many devices can be used for test?

Tags: ios, ipad

I have several iPad devices for developing and testing apps and all of them belong to my customers. How many different devices can i use for developing and testing?

And I am not sure if it's a good method to develop and test the customer application on his own device? Because I have to give the iPads to my customers after finishing development their apps.

Hope I could tell my question well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

100 devices / developer account.

but You can register an account on TestFlight app there you can publish your app for teating to all your customers.

https://testflightapp.com

Comment: TestFlight does not remove the 100 devices limit. But it makes the distribution process much more pleasant.

Comment: Also, it's 100 devices / account / year: You cannot just remove fifty devices and add another fifty until the next year.

Comment: 100 devices / developer account is the answer i absoutely need.